# Problem with Invoke to parallelize foreach

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have a problem with using System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach. The body foreach progressBar want to update.
But Invoke method sometimes freeze.

I attach the code to the form which is prograssbar and Buton.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    pforeach();
    Text = (DateTime.Now - start).ToString();
}


private void pforeach()
{
    int[] intArray = new int[60];
    int totalcount = intArray.Length;
    object lck = new object();
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<int, int>(intArray,
    () => 0,
    (x, loop, count) =>
    {
        int value = 0;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        count++;
        value = (int)(100f / (float)totalcount * (float)count);

        Set(value);
        return count;
    },
    (x) =>
    {

    });
}

private void Set(int i)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var result = Invoke(new Action<int>(Set), i);
    }
    else
        progressBar1.Value = i;
}
```

Sometimes it passes without a problem, but usually it freeze on 
`var result = Invoke (new Action <int> (Set), i)`.
Try to kick me in the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that `Invoke` (and queueing a `Task` to the UI `TaskScheduler`) both require the UI thread to be processing its message loop. However, it is not. It is still waiting for the `Parallel.ForEach` loop to complete. This is why you see a deadlock.

If you want the `Parallel.ForEach` to run without blocking the UI thread, wrap it into a `Task`, as such:

```
private TaskScheduler ui;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(pforeach)
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            task.Wait(); // Ensure errors are propogated to the UI thread.
            Text = (DateTime.Now - start).ToString(); 
        }, ui);
} 

private void pforeach() 
{ 
    int[] intArray = new int[60]; 
    int totalcount = intArray.Length; 
    object lck = new object(); 
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach<int, int>(intArray, 
    () => 0, 
    (x, loop, count) => 
    { 
        int value = 0; 
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); 
        count++; 
        value = (int)(100f / (float)totalcount * (float)count); 

        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => Set(value),
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            ui).Wait();
        return count; 
    }, 
    (x) => 
    { 

    }); 
} 

private void Set(int i) 
{ 
    progressBar1.Value = i; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at how I did this and this change may help you:

In my constructor I have this line:

`TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();`

Then I do this:

```
    private void changeProgressBar()
    {
        (new Task(() =>
        {
            mainProgressBar.Value++;
            mainProgressTextField.Text = mainProgressBar.Value + " of " + mainProgressBar.Maximum;
        })).Start(uiScheduler);
    }
```

This gets rid of needing to use Invoke, and if you use the `Task` method then it may solve your problem.

I think these were all in `System.Threading.Tasks;`